# How to get correct post_count and found_posts within include file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created an include file which allows me to filter my post queries using a category dropdown. I am trying to get the `post_count` and `found_posts` dynamically so I can display `Showing 6 out of 12 Posts` for example. I am including this filter on a custom page template with a custom WP_Query, but I am getting `Showing 1 out of 1 Posts` despite there being 10+ posts. I believe the reason it is doing this is because the filter include is using the single page query rather than my custom post query. How can I go about updating this so that the filter uses my custom post query?

**inc/filter.php:**

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    $count = $wp_query->post_count;
    $total = $wp_query->found_posts;
?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <?php $get_categories = get_categories(); ?>
            <select>
                <option selected disabled>Select category</option>
                <option value="all">All</option>
                <?php
                    if ($get_categories) :
                        foreach ($get_categories as $cat) :
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>">
                        <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php endforeach; 
                        endif;
                    ?>
            </select>
            <div class="shown-posts">Showing <span class="visible-posts"><?php echo $count; ?></span> of <span class="total-posts"><?php echo $total; ?></span> posts</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And here's my custom page template:**

```
<?php get_header();?>
<?php 
    $posts = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post'
    ));
?>
<?php if($posts->have_posts()): ?>
    // Here's where I'm including the filter file
    <?php get_template_part( 'inc/filter' ); ?>
    <div class="container post-container">
        <div class="row row-eq-height">
            <?php while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post();
                the_title();
            endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to pass variable to templates included via `get_template_part()` is to add them to the WordPress `query_vars`.

So in inc/filter.php remove all of this...

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    $count = $wp_query->post_count;
    $total = $wp_query->found_posts;
?>
```

Then in the main template add...

```
<?php 
    $posts = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post'
    ));

    set_query_var( 'count', $posts->post_count );
    set_query_var( 'total', $posts->found_posts );
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

## UPDATE 2023

(since WP 5.5 mid-2020 actually, even though a lot of people don't use it

In the main template, only one line :

```
// Here's where I'm including the filter file
<?php
get_template_part('inc/filter', null, [
    'count' => $posts->post_count,
    'total' => $posts->found_posts
]);
?>
```

### WordPress doc

Starting in WordPress 5.5, the template loading functions will now allow additional arguments to be passed through to the matched template file using a new $args parameter.

For years, theme developers wishing to pass data to template files have had to use less than ideal workarounds. This included the use of global variables, set_query_var(), the include( locate_template() ) pattern, or own version of get_template_part(), and so on.

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/17/passing-arguments-to-template-files-in-wordpress-5-5/

Answer (score 1):

Change the calculation in **inc/filter.php** to:

```
<?php
    $count = $posts->post_count;
    $total = $posts->found_posts;
?>
```

You are correct that the global WP_Query object is pointing at the single page containing all of this. [Instantiating a new WP_Query does not override the global WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#multiple-loops). Finally, note that nothing about your scope changes when you [include the filter file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) -- so, just keep using the `$posts` variable that you already setup.